# Using colored output for awk, or grep multiple pattern search in and condition

Tags: bash, awk, grep

For my work, I'm frequently searching for patterns in files. Generally I use the `grep --color=auto` to color the search pattern. Now when I'm searching for multiple patterns, all of which should be present in a line, I use `grep pattern1 file|grep pattern2|grep pattern3` or `awk '/pattern1/&&/pattern2'`. But this way, in grep I lose the coloring which is highly helpful for me, or in awk, I don't know any way to color only the pattern string. When it becomes too troublesome, I use `grep pattern1 file|grep pattern2|grep pattern3|grep -E "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3"`.

So is there any way in grep to mention multiple patterns in and condition? ( I think regular expressions should support it, but could not find any, specially the ordering of patterns are not fixed)

Or is there any way to color print the awk search patterns?

Any short compact approach is welcome (for I will be using many times a day )

Comment: see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/6540890/297323

Comment: @FredrikPihl I searched with awk color output earlier, all of them are actually formatting a field, not a pattern. So i can make the 2nd field in green if i want, but i don't know if my pattern is going to come in second field or 3rd field. What i want is that pattern should come in green, irrespective of where it is coming

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `--color=always` when piping from grep to retain color:

```
grep pat1 --color=always | grep pat2
```

Comment: Thanks @perreal, It saved the day :) . But still, i'm curious, Is there any way in grep to combine patterns in "and" condition? If "or" condition is present, why "and" is not present ? I am not talking about pipe the output, but a single grep, which will look for strings which contains all the pattern given, in any order

Comment: the way to do and is 1) piping, 2) using something like `grep -e 'pat1.*pat2' -e 'pat2.*pat1' input`. Perhaps it is missing because it is redundant (you cannot `or` with pipes).

Answer (score 6):

You could build your own `shell script/function` using `awk` and escape codes:

Given the file `Awk color text` the following will print the matched word `Awk` in cyan:

```
$ awk '/Awk/{gsub(/Awk/,"\033[1;36m&\033[1;000m");print}' file
Awk color test
```

This principle can easily be extended for multiple patterns added `This line ends here` to line one.

```
$ awk '/Awk/&&/This/{gsub(/Awk|This/,"\033[1;36m&\033[1;000m");print}' file
Awk color test This line ends here.
```

Check out [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) for some more information on shell colours.

Comment: Thanks @sudo_O, I knew about the gsub, but never thought of using it this way. It perfectly answers the second question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use curly braces for parameter expansion:

```
grep --color=always -e{pat1,pat2}
```

which effectively is the same as:

```
grep --color=always -e foo -e bar
```

Note this will return results with `pat1` AND/OR `pat2`.

(I don't have enough reputation points to add this post as a comment)